Why does the sign on the variable changes with the lag while running ARDL model?
The dependent variable of the model is mortality rate, while independent variable is mean: Mean year of schooling, and GDP for the Gross domestic product, percentage change. While they are all either I(0) or I(1), so I use the ARDL model. However the coefficient of mean is positive while lag coefficient of mean is negative. is this normal , how should I interpret it? 
